# Delete all files in directory except .bak .$av and .pen using batch script

Tags: batch-file, extension-methods, delete-file

I would like to know how to delete files (using batch script) of every extension except those with the extension .bak, .$av and .pen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying it out, please make a back up of your files so that you don't lose data forever!

**NOTE:** Use at your own risk, it does a mass DELETE of everything!

```
SET /p ExcludeFiles = What file type should be kept (NOT deleted)? Type the file name(s) inside parantheses. 

Example: (bak) or ($av pen)     

SET /p MapDrive = What drive letter is the folder in? 

Example: c or n  

SET /p Directory = Drag the folder you would like to modify into this command prompt then press ENTER.     

%MapDrive%:
cd %Directory%

attrib +a *.* /s
echo %date%
for %%i in %ExcludeFiles% do attrib -a *.%%i /s
echo %date%
del %Directory%\*.* /s /a:a /q

echo %date%
attrib +a %Directory%\*.* /s
echo %date%
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify the operating system or the script language you are wanting to use which would be helpful.

However here is a general purpose type of script in fairly generic terms.

An fairly general approach would be to create a subfolder, copy or move the files you want to keep into the subfolder, delete all the files in the folder you want to clear, and then move the files you saved in the sub folder back to the original folder.

Most delete file types of commands are designed to have you specify the files you want to delete rather than the files that you do not want to delete.

And actually with this question, I am wondering now why that would not be a nice extension to a delete command.

Now if you are going to need to do file tree deletes meaning to traverse a file directory hierarchy to delete files except for these that you want to keep, that will be a bit more difficult.  One way to do that would be to traverse the file tree and perform this same action on each directory.

Another option would be to generate a list of all of the files in the folder and use a utility such as sed to modify the file listing so that you create an ad hoc, on the fly script which will then be executed.  This script would be modified by the utility so that those files you want to keep will be removed from the list and the ones you want to delete would have the line of that file name in the listing modified to perform a delete.

I would definitely do some serious testing before deploying the on the fly script execution method though.

Answer (score 0):

Use FINDSTR to ignore file names with your particular extensions. Pipe the results of DIR /B to FINDSTR and use FOR /F to process the results.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d^|findstr /vire "\.bak \.\$av \.pen"') do @del "%%F"
```

If run from the command line then change `%%F` to `%F`.